# Using RVM, Rails 3.0.7 is messed up after installing Rails 3.1.0 beta1

Tags: rvm

Using rvm I installed and am using Ruby 1.9.2p180.

I created a gemset called rails3tutorial and, using it, installed Rails 3.0.7, created "sample_app", then used bundle to install. Very nice.

Then I created a new gemset called rails310b1, installed Rails 3.1.0 Beta 1, created an app, and bundle install'd...but it turned out I was not actually switched to the rails310b1 gemset, and so I ended up installing to ruby-1.9.2p180's default gemset (is that @global?...). I then manually deleted all the gems that had been installed!

Then I switched to rails310b1, and bundle install'd, created an app, fired up the app -- golden.

Now I switch back to the rails3tutorial gemset, and cd to the app created using it, and I get errors when running rails commands like...

```
$ rails generate integration_test layout_links
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/rails:19:in `load': no such     file to load -- /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/rails-3.1.0.beta1/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

It's looking for /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/**rails-3.1.0.beta1**/bin/rails but why?! $PATH looks fine.

Any suggestions as to what is messed up and how to clean this up, or is it best if I wipe out all my gems/gemsets and start over?...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just run bundle update/install to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nice screencast with basics of RVM http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm but it mostly comes to using rubies:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
cd ~/projects/my-app
touch Gemfile
rvm use --create --rvmrc 1.9.3@rails32
gem install bundler rails
bundle exec rails new .
bundle install
bundle exec rails generate integration_test layout_links
```

please note you need to prefix most of the commands with `bundle exec` there is my gem that should save you from this problem [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler).

also make sure you use `.rvmrc` files for every project so when you switch dir in console the proper ruby environment is set, the `--rvmrc` switch used above will generate one for you.